# What is the connotation of the word 'O'?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, vocatives

What is the author trying to convey with the word 'O' in the following:

> He has told you, O man, what is good;

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/O#Particle

Comment: @RegDwigнt Thank you for this! I was having the hardest time looking for it on wikipedia

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the [vocative case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocative_case#English):

> A vocative expression is an expression of direct address, wherein the identity of the party being spoken to is set forth expressly within a sentence...
>   Historically, or in poetic or rhetorical speech, the vocative role in English may also be shown by prefacing the noun or noun phrase with the English word "O".

Modern English does not have a formal vocative case, and may use the [nominative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_case) to fill that role.

The cases are more apparent when looking at some other languages like Latin. A well-known passage from [Alice's Adventures in Wonderland where Alice speaks to a mouse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse_%28Alice%27s_Adventures_in_Wonderland%29) reviews them, ending in the vocative:

> 'O Mouse, do you know the way out of this pool? I am very tired of swimming about here, O Mouse!' (Alice thought this must be the right way of speaking to a mouse: she had never done such a thing before, but she remembered having seen in her brother's Latin Grammar, 'A mouse—of a mouse—to a mouse—a mouse—O mouse!')

Note that the "[O](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/o)" itself can be considered an interjection, much like "[Oh](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/oh)" (thanks, @Kit and @Cerberus!); it might be more clear to say it is an interjection accompanying a noun that is in the (unmarked) vocative, "man" in your example.

Comment: Unless it's the story of - in which case 'O' has rather different connotations

Answer (score 2):

'O' is an archaic word used to emphasize the subject being addressed. In your example (Malachi chapter 2 IIRC) the speaker wishes to address "man," so he says "O man," not to be confused with the modern idiom "oh man."